# How can I open a facebook.session with access token and permissions in android?

Tags: session, facebook-access-token

How can I open a session with the specified permission?

I open a `com.facebook.Session` with API `Session#openActiveSessionWithAccessToken()` in an `android.app.Service`. 
And then the opened session is used to get me/friendrequests by sending a request.
It results in an error as below:

```
{HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 289, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#289) Requires extended permission: read_requests} ;
```

The permissions retrieved by using mSession.getPermissions() before creating the requests are as follows:

```
[read_requests, read_mailbox, manage_notifications]
```

Could you tell me what's wrong with my code?
Or could you tell me what should I do?

Code:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("read_requests", "read_mailbox", "manage_notifications");
....
AccessToken token =
              AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(mAccount.getAccessToken(), new    Date(mAccount.getExpireTime()), null,
                AccessTokenSource.CLIENT_TOKEN, PERMISSIONS);
    mSession = Session.openActiveSessionWithAccessToken(mContext, token, new StatusCallback(){
        @Override
        public void call(Session aSession, SessionState aState, Exception aException) {
            if (aException != null) {
                Log.i(Log.Tag.OTHER, TAG + "#createSession#call " + aException.getMessage());
            }
            //getNewInfos();

        }
    });
```

I have solved this problem.